# Peak points and a decreasing subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need some help with the following:
[image]

For the subsequences I said

$ \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_k} = 1 $ for $ n_k=4k+1 $ As in these cases we get $sin(\frac {n\pi}{2})=1 $

$ \lim_{p \to \infty} a_{n_p} = 0 $ for $ n_p=2^p $ Here $sin(\frac {n\pi}{2})=0 $

$ \lim_{q \to \infty} a_{n_q} = -1 $ for $ n_q=4q-1 $ And here here $sin(\frac {n\pi}{2})=-1 $

For part b) I think the answer is that it has infinitely many peak points which are all the elements of $ a_{n_k} $ because it is a decreasing subsequence. Am I right ? And how can I show that it is a decreasing subsequence? I had troubles with that. Many thanks.

Comment: $(n^2+n)/(n^2+1)=1+[(n-1)/(n^2+1)]$ should help with the decreasing part. I don't know what a "peak point" is.

Comment: $ a_k $ is a peak point of $ (a_k) $ if $ a_k \geq a_n \forall n \geq k$
I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: Actually I am not even sure how to show that a sequence is decreasing. I have only done so for recursively defined ones. And this one is a subsequence.  Should I just consider $ a_{n+1}-a_n $ ?
Eh sorry ,for my definition of a peak point it should be of $(a_n)$ not $(a_k) $

Comment: Sounds like a plan.

Comment: After calculating $ a_{n+1}-a_n=1+\frac {(n+1)-1}{(n+1)^2+1}-(1+ \frac{n-1}{n^2+1})$ I get $\frac {2-n}{((n+1)^2+1)(n-1)} $ which has to be less than zero. Is that it? Its less than zero for $n\geq 2$ though. So since our subsequence goes as $a_5 , a_9, a_{13} ...$ we can conclude that?

Comment: Looks good to me. Write it up and post it as an answer (the software may ask you to wait a few hours).

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry for a dumb question but why write it as an answer? I am new to this website.

Comment: Questions without answers get circulated back to the front page at random intervals. To avoid that, it's better if a question has an answer (and the answer has been accepted). Also, it's not bad to have some practice in writing up solutions to problems. Finally, it's a way to earn points on this website.

Comment: Ok , done . Hopefully its alright ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part a) 
The subsequences are:

$ \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_k} = 1 $ for $ n_k=4k+1 \ k\in N_+ $ As in these cases we get $sin(\frac {n\pi}{2})=1 $ and so $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2+n}{n^2+1}=1 $

$ \lim_{p \to \infty} a_{n_p} = 0 $ for $ n_p=2p \ \in N_+$ Here $sin(\frac {n\pi}{2})=0 $. I.e. $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n^2+1}=0 $

$ \lim_{q \to \infty} a_{n_q} = -1 $ for $ n_q=4q-1 \ q\in N_+ $ And here here $sin(\frac {n\pi}{2})=-1 $ and for this one we have $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-n^2+n}{n^2+1}=-1 $

b) A definition first. $a_k $ is a peak point of $(a_n) n\in N_+$ if $a_k \geq a_n   \forall n\geq k $
In our case the largest values of $a_n$ occur in $a_{n_k} $ subsequence and it is a decreasing subsequence and hence has infinitely many peak points. To prove that it is a decreasing subsequence we consider: 
 $ a_{n+1}-a_n=1+\frac{(n+1)-1}{(n+1)^2+1} -(1+\frac{(n-1}{(n^2+1})=\frac{2-n}{((n+1)^2+1)(n-1)} \leq0$ for $n\geq 2$ and as our subsequence starts with the term $a_5, n=5$ the result follows.